# How to change hdri opacity

Tags: hdri

I would like to change the opacity of ah hardy, but not make it completely transparent
I tried to use a mix shader mode, but the factor doesn't provide a gradual effect, rather it gives either a fully transparent result or a none transparent result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "transparent" does not really apply to HDRI map representing the environment. It has nothing to be transparent to except darkness. So you can mix it with black and it will be darker or you can mix it with another color and it will be as if it was transparent while the other color was behind it. You do it sort of correctly - you can mix the shader or the color with whatever you want with Mix Shader or Mix Color nodes.

[image]

You adjust how "transparent" it is by adjusting factor value - the one called "Fac" 0 meaning the top input is fully visible, 1 meaning the bottom input is fully visible.